# Rails query where has_many relationship matching query doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Subscription` model which has_many `Transaction`s.

I want to find all subscriptions for which a transaction matching a certain query doesn't exist.

This is the manual looping code that yields the correct result. However, I'd like to do the same using a `where` query instead.

```
# Find all subs that don't have a transaction where foo == bar
subs = []
Subscription.all.each do |sub|
  if sub.transactions.find { |tran| tran.foo == 'bar' } == nil
    subs.push(sub)
  end
end
```

I've tried so many different options but none of them produce the correct result:

```
Subscription.includes(:transactions).where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM subscriptions.transactions where transactions.foo = 'bar')")

Subscription.includes(:transactions).where("(select count(*) from transactions where foo='bar') = 0")

Subscription.where(Transaction.where("transactions.foo != 'bar'").limit(1).count == 0)

Subscription.joins(:transactions).group('subscriptions.id').having('count(transactions.foo = 'bar') = 0')

Subscription.where(Transaction.group().where("count(transactions.foo != 'bar') = 0"))

Subscription.where('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transactions WHERE transactions.foo = 'bar') =  0')

Transaction.left_outer_joins(:transactions).group("transactions.id").having("count(transactions.id)>0")

Subscription.left_outer_joins(:transactions).where.not(transactions: {foo: 'bar'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first select all the transactions where foo is equal to bar.
Then you could select all subscription ids which are not in the above result, which would give an Active Record query like this:

```
Subscription.where.not(id: Transaction.where('foo = ?', 'bar').select(:subscription_id).uniq)
```

This will generate a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE (subscriptions.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT transactions.subscription_id WHERE transactions.foo = 'bar'))
```

Comment: Hmm, this is not working. It's giving me more subscription objects than totally exist. I think the reason is because it is giving us subscriptions where transactions.foo != bar, even if one of its transactions.foo == bar. For example, if a subscription has 2 trans, one where foo != bar and one where foo == bar, it seems like this still returns that sub, even though we don't want it. If a subscription contains even one transaction that has foo == bar, we don't want to return it.

Comment: I feel like incorporating `count` somehow might be the way to go. This is the pseudocode for what I want: `sub.where(count(sub.transactions.where(foo == bar)) == 0)`

Comment: You are absolutely correct, apologies I didn't pick it up the first time. I have updated my answer, can you please give that a try (unfortunately I am not in front of a computer to try)

Comment: That did it! With a slight modification: `Subscription.where.not(id: Transaction.where('foo = ?', 'bar').select(:subscription_id).uniq).map { |e| e.subscription_id })` (Added mapping to return array of ids rather than transaction objects. Perhaps there's a way to do this with directly with SQL?)

Comment: Awesome, you can use the pluck method provided by active record. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck. It should then become Subscription.where.not(id: Transcation.where('foo = ?', 'bar').pluck(:id).uniq))